# Excel Formula: If text from 1 column matches text in 2 different columns, subtract their adjacent values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Sheet1 I have in Col A a list of ±1200 names and Cols B-AD are dates. 
Sheet2 layout is identical to Sheet 1, but the list of names in Col A on Sheet2 does not match the list in Col A Sheet1 identically.
In Sheet3 I have the total list of names from Sheet1 and Sheet2 in Column A.

If the name in Sheet3 Col A is found in Sheet1 Col A **AND** in Sheet2 Col A, then subtract the value of Sheet1 Col B from the value of Sheet2 Col B.

Can someone please help me with a formula I can plug into my macro?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** This is a place for programmers to ask/answer questions when a solution to the problem can't be found elsewhere. Please see the [tour] as well as "[ask]", plus there's important tips about **providing examples** at "[mcve]". Please show that you made an **effort** to find a solution yourself before asking for help (on a _specific_ issue). You can always [edit] your question to include details (code/screenshots/etc) showing what you've tried so far. More info: [help/on-topic]. See also [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg for your feedback. I've been searching for hours trying various combinations of Index/match options, none of which have worked at all. So, I'm afraid there isn't much effort I can show.

Comment: It's okay, we like to see what you've tried, especially what *didn't* work. (If it "worked", you wouldn't be here!)  It's pretty hard to troubleshoot a *specific* problem without seeing what you have and what you're trying to do  (no data, no code, etc.)   ...or perhaps the answer below solved your issue?

Comment: Thank you again for checking in @ashleedawg. I can definitely work with the answer below. I just need an easy way to figure how I increase the col_index_num when the formula is copied across about 31 columns. Copying down is not an issue. The formula goes into a macro. Thanks for following up. I do appreciate it.

Comment: `col_index_num`, as in the `2` in the formula below, correct?  Which column is it starting in, and which column is 31 over?  Is it Columns `B:AD` (as mentioned in your question) - actually 29 columns total?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel on this machine, but something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet1.A1:B10,2)-VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet2.A1:B10>,2),"No match")
```

Should work

(the above formula was done in LibreOffice, you'll need to adjust for Excel)

Comment: Thank you so very, very much! This seems to work perfectly. I was totally overcomplicating the issue trying to do INDEX Matches.

Comment: Just one last question: Is there an easy way to copy a VLOOKUP function across about 31 columns with the column index number increasing as you copy across?

Comment: That's different enough from your original question that you may want to ask it separately. The quick response is yes, by using references to cells values for the column index.

Answer (score 0):

The formula above, adjusted for Excel:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet1!A1:B10,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet2!A1:B10,2,FALSE),"No Match!")
```

---

## Auto-update the Column Index number when copying a formula:

There are a number of ways you can have a number in a formula "auto-update" as you copy or "fill"/"drag" it across columns or rows.

### Here are two simple methods:

1. Use a "Helper Row" such as in this simplified example:

[image: helper row example]

It's called a "Helper Row" since it's "helping" another formula, and also since it's not part of your actual report, you can **hide the row** after it's setup, and the formula will still function properly...  ("no one will ever know!")

2. Use the `Column()` function to get the appropriate Index ID:

[image: column() exanple]

If you want `1` to be returned while in `Column E` (the 5th letter of the alphabet), and the number should increase as the column letter "increases", you can use `COLUMN()-4` (Since *`5 - 4 = 1`*).

---

If I understand correctly, the formula needs to start in `Column B`, and the `Column Index Number` should be `2`, so since `B` is the 2nd letter of the alphabet, we won't need to deduct anything from the `COLUMN()` function, so your complete formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet1!A1:B10,COLUMN(),FALSE)-VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet2!A1:B10,COLUMN(),FALSE),"No Match!")
```